# MariaDB extracting JSON value from array

Tags: json, mariadb

I have a JSON field:

```
[{"Filename":"20210914_.ext"},
 {"Soil":"Sand"},
 {"Name":"Simon"}]
```

I want the value "Simon", just the text, nothing else:  I do:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(jsonParam, '$[*].Name') FROM tblName WHERE biPK=1;
```

The result is:

```
["Simon"]
```

What do I have to do to the query to get just **Simon**, no brackets and no quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(jsonParam, '$[*].Name']) FROM tblName WHERE biPK=1;
```

Result:

```
Simon
```